# Update javascript files in live site without changing code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget-package

My website is using the jquery framework and UI Plug-in. I want to update them to latest versions, whenever they are released. So what is best way to update files in a live site without modifying any code or publishing the site again?

Comment: If there are no breaking changes you can just upload the new file to the server. If there are breaking changes then you will have to amend your code to fit the updated library methods.

Comment: There is no auto-update, and there is no online "this is the latest jquery" for you to use. The reasons why are presented here: https://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/